How to remove a freewheel-hub from a Specialized ebike?
What is the trick to remove the freewheel-hub from a hub-motor driven Specialized Turbo from 2015?
are hubs all left-hand threaded?

simply apply wrenches to both ends of axle and undo in normal direction.
